# Sequelize js node Transactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new to sequelize right now I'm a bit confused how to use the transactions of sequelize.

My project launches events that can be called at the same time,here is a minimized example with two events, eventA or eventB, and a minimized model User.

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('Uer', {
        stuff: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            defaultValue: ""
        }
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            getAllUsers : function (resultsCallback) {                  
                this.findAll().complete(function(err, users) {
                    resultsCallback(err, users);                   
                })
            }
        },
        instanceMethods: {           

            update1: function (transaction) {
                    var stuff = this.stuff + "1";

                    this.updateUserAttributes(document, transaction, function(err, results){

                });
            },

            update2: function (transaction) {
                    var stuff = this.stuff + "2";

                    var document = {};
                    document.stuff = stuff;

                this.updateUserAttributes(document, transaction, function(err, results){

                });
            },

            updateUserAttributes : function(document, transaction, resultsCallback) {

                var docArray = [];                

                var call = _.after(Object.keys(document).length, function(){


                    this
                    .updateAttributes(document, docArray,  {
                        transaction: transaction
                    })
                    .complete(function(err, results) {
                        if (!!err) {
                            console.log('An error occurred while updating', err)   
                        } else if (!results) {
                            console.log('Failed to update User.')
                        }       

                        resultsCallback(err, results);  
                    });

                }.bind(this));   

                for(var key in document){
                    docArray.push(String(key));
                    call();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

eventA

```
...
    sequelize.transaction(function(transaction) {
        User.sync().success(function(err, restuls){
            User.getAllUsers(function(err, results){
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                    results[i].update1(transaction)
                }
                transaction.commit();
            });     
        });
    });
...
```

eventB

```
    ....
sequelize.transaction(function(transaction) {
    User.sync().success(function(err, restuls){
        User.getAllUsers(function(err, results){
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                    results[i].update2(transaction)
                }
                transaction.commit();
            });     
        });
});
...
```

My problem is, for example the first occurrence  of events A and B are called but only one of them remains in the DB sutff  = "2" instead of stuff = "12".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to others that have the same problem. I ended up solving this with a row locking.

Also I wasn't passing the transaction to all `.save()` and `.updateAttributtes()`, as well as I wasn't using the update attributes correctly, that is (at least for what I saw):

> updateAttributes({fieldName: newFieldValue}, {fields:[fieldName],
>   transaction:transaction})

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation and use this method everywhere.

```
function trans(callback, done) {
    sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
        function commit(callback) {
            t.commit().done(function (err) {
                console.log('commited')
                if (callback)
                    callback(err)
            })
        }

        function rollback(rollbackErr, callback) {
            t.rollback().done(function (err) {
                if (callback)
                    callback(err || rollbackErr)
            })
        }

        t.done(function () {
            if (done) done()
        })

        callback(commit, rollback, t)
    })
}



function someExecution(data, callback){

    trans(function(commit, rollback, t){
        Model.create(data, {transaction: t}).done(function(err, obj){
            if (err) return rollback(err, callback)
            Model.findAll({where: {some: 1}}, {transaction: t}).done(function(err, list){
                if (err) return rollback(err, callback)
                commit(callback)
            })
        })
    })

}
```

Comment: Although that cleans a bit my code, I've got the same problem. When the events are called at the same time, they get bot the same information, and when they are updating the attribute they simple ignore both transaction opened transactions.